# undefined variable in foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

all I am new to CodeIgniter. I am trying to show the user logs from the database for the particular user. I don't know what happened it throwing an error like an Undefined variable.

I have users list on my dashboard if I click on particular user edit button it will take me to another page where I am trying to show that user logs but some point it's not working.

Controller:

```
public function userlogs() {
      if ($this->input->post('temp_user_id')) {
        $id = $this->input->post('temp_user_id');
        $this->session->set_userdata('temp_user_id', $id);
    } elseif ($this->session->userdata('temp_user_id')) {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('temp_user_id');
    }

    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged') && $id) {
        $data['userlogs'] = $this->Org_model->getLogs($id);
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view("organisation/user_edit", $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User Id not captured.');
        redirect('Organisation/editOrg');
    }
}
```

Controller 1:

```
public function editUser() {
    if ($this->input->post('temp_user_id')) {
        $id = $this->input->post('temp_user_id');
        $this->session->set_userdata('temp_user_id', $id);
    } elseif ($this->session->userdata('temp_user_id')) {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('temp_user_id');
    }

    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged') && $id) {
        $data['userdata'] = $this->Org_model->getUsersData($id);
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view("organisation/user_edit", $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User Id not captured.');
        redirect('Organisation/editOrg');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function getLogs($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('log_table');
    $this->db->where('userid',$id );

    if ($query = $this->db->get()) {
         return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Event</th>
                                <th>Date / Time</th>
                                <th>IP Address</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <!-- Displaying Fetched Details from Database -->
                            <?php


                              foreach ($userlogs as $userlog) {

                                    $timestamp = $userlog->entertime;
                                    echo $timestamp;
                                    ?>

                                    <tr>

                                        <td><?php echo $userlog->userid; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $userlog->log_operation; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php
                            $format = 'DATE_RFC822';
                            echo standard_date($format, $timestamp);
                                    ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $userlog->ip; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                }

                            ?>    
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
```

But it throwing error like  `Undefined variable: userlogs`

i didn't understand where i did mistake

Can anyone help me

How to resolve that issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The view code you are showing here is of `organisation/user_edit.php`?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: check this is not empty `$data['userlogs']`

Comment: and what is url ? when you see this error

Comment: this is the url http://localhost/SVN/Project_X/Organisation/editUser

Comment: so you need to show controller code for `editUser `. currently you are showing `userlogs` code

Comment: i updated my question and i added edituser function can you please check

Comment: okay got it. check my answer below @suresh

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `userlogs` data in `editUser` controller method. try below code

```
public function editUser() {
    if ($this->input->post('temp_user_id')) {
        $id = $this->input->post('temp_user_id');
        $this->session->set_userdata('temp_user_id', $id);
    } elseif ($this->session->userdata('temp_user_id')) {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('temp_user_id');
    }

    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged') && $id) {
       $data['userlogs'] = $this->Org_model->getLogs($id);
        $data['userdata'] = $this->Org_model->getUsersData($id);
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view("organisation/user_edit", $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User Id not captured.');
        redirect('Organisation/editOrg');
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is working perfectly..thank you..thanks a lot..i am trying from past few hours..

Comment: i have one more doubt can i ask?

Comment: glad to help @suresh

Comment: you can raise another question if you have new doubt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679388/get-active-session-users-in-codeigniter here is the new question link

Comment: can you please help me how to solve that one..i was trying from past few days but i didn't get any idea of how to do that